# How to disable iPhone 'app not active' flashing banner

Tags: ios, iphone

My app checks the GPS while my app is not the active app and I use AVAudioplayer too in background.

It works fine and stays in the background doing its thing, but ios7 displays this red top banner with my app name flashing on it when it is not the active app.

How can I disable this banner, it is annoying to use other apps that are squished down 1 line?

I know this can be done as I have other GPS based background apps that don't display this flashing banner.

EDIT - So we found the answer quickly but the solution evades me:
If I stop OpenEars pocketsphinxController from listening with a button that calls this method while the program is active, the banner disappears when the app loses focus:

```
-(void) mystopListening{
   NSLog(@"Tried to stop listening");
   [pocketsphinxController stopListening];
}
```

BUT if I call the same method from my app delegate with (I had to import my view controller.h file in my app delegate.h and add -(void) nystopListening; in my view controller.h to make the below execute properly):

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application{
   myViewController * vc = [[myViewController alloc]init];
   [vc mystopListening];
}
```

The banner persists!  It is a little like ios7 has decided I am a recording culprit before I even have a chance to turn it off. OR, am I even turning it off?
How do I do this effectively and in what event?

EDIT - So it turns out I am not really turning pocketsphinxController off when 'mystopListening' is called from the app delegate.  I know this because it DOES log the 'Tried to stop listening' when called from app delegate but the pocketsphinxController does not respond with its 'pocketsphinxDidStopListening' method.   PocketsphinxController does call its 'pocketsphinxDidStopListening' method when I call 'mystopListening' from a button while the app is active.

Why won't the pocketsphinxController respond when called from from the app delegate, I must be doing it wrong?

Thanks,Carmen

Comment: Are you recording audio?

Comment: Yes I use openears too, sorry I didn't think it relevant.

Comment: If you record audio, that's probably what the red banner is. Stop audio recording (background) and it should go away.

Comment: This looks like the answer, thank-you very much!

Comment: sangony, please see edited question, I am having trouble carrying out your suggestion, thanks, Carmen

Comment: post the code inside your stopListening method.

Comment: That is all the code, I call a method from pocketsphinxcontroller interface, sorry if not what you asked, I'm a newbie, how do I find their code?. Carmen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was not really calling the original pockectsphinxcontroller instance from my app delegate.

As a workaround to the problem I did this:

My app always has a timer running, so in my app delegate where I get notice of when app goes to inactive and comes back active, I just set global flags so my timer can know app active status. Then my timer just uses pockecsphinxcontroller methods to stop and start listening and voila, the banner is no more while app not active.

Comment: Just saw your additional comments. You are right, by creating a new VC you were simply instantiating a second copy of your class. Your subsequent stop method was pointing to the new copy instead of your original one. I used to get confused with that all the time! Fantastic you solved your own problem! +1